# Indexed percent rank in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, percentage, percentile

I have a percent rank below

```
=PERCENTRANK(INDEX(T$2:T$28557,MATCH($A408,$A$2:$A$28557,0)):INDEX(T$2:T$28557,MATCH($A408,$A$2:$A$28557,1)),T407,3)*100
```

I want it to return a ranking only for matching in column A. But it's returning a ranking for the whole data set. For example, I have a list of schools in column A and I want to find the percent ranking of students in each school, not the entire district. Is there a formula for that?

Here's some mock data. So I need to find out what the percent ranks in columns D and F are for each school independent of all the others.

[Mock Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kh1wV.png)

Comment: is column A sorted ascending?

Comment: @ScottCraner Yes it is.

Answer (score 0):

As your data is sorted use COUNTIF() to get the end of the school name:

Put this in D2 and copy down:

```
=PERCENTRANK(INDEX(C$2:C$21,MATCH($A2,$A$2:$A$21,0)):INDEX(C$2:C$21,MATCH($A2,$A$2:$A$21,0)+COUNTIF($A$2:$A$21,$A2)-1),C2,3)*100
```

Put this in F2 and copy down

```
=PERCENTRANK(INDEX(E$2:E$21,MATCH($A2,$A$2:$A$21,0)):INDEX(E$2:E$21,MATCH($A2,$A$2:$A$21,0)+COUNTIF($A$2:$A$21,$A2)-1),E2,3)*100
```

[image]

Comment: That works for the first school on the list but it doesn't continue past that. When I change schools in column A is there a way to get it to start over using just that school?

Comment: then I am not understanding your setup and desired output.  Please mock up some test data and expected output.

Comment: please edit the original post with the update.  comments cannot be formatted.

Comment: @APretender see edit.  formula works for me with your data.  The only thing I changed was the cell references.